# Entity Framework with React

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework, reactjs

I'm creating my shop app with asp.net and i builded data base with Entity Framework Code First, I'm using MsSQL , I've decided now to add React.js, and my question is. Can i use @Model or sth like that on .jsx files to load records from data base? Or must i convert it to json file, If yes how can i do that? If none of this, can someone explain me how to do this to save my app and pick the best way to do this with React.js.

```
var CourseDetails = function(data){
    return (
        <table className="table">
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Autor</th>
                    {/* Here i wanna to load eg. @Model.PC.ID from viewmodel instead of {data.autor} from .json file */}
                    <td>{data.author}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Czas trwania kursu</th>
                    <td>{data.duration}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         )
}
```

Comment: With React you create Single Page Applications. I guess you are using ASP.Net MVC for your app which is a totally different thing. I'd suggest you create a API with .Net and run both apps, frontend and backend separately

Comment: I watched on one tutorial that someone created a shop using react.js with JSON data, can't i use insted of json my entity framework data to it ? look on this https://reactjs.net, u think should i skip react on this app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is backend code that helps your server fetch database resources.

My suggestion is to treat your front-end and back-end as two projects. Build a Restful API layer that exposes your data (without or without the Entity Framework) as your backend.

Then build your front-end using Reach to fetch the data.

Comment: I found this: https://reactjs.net/ . How i can show it with my app that i can do React.js, I need it only for CV, it's bad idea ?

Comment: In terms of learning React it would probably be easier learning it the plain way, following the normal tutorial. The React.net example, in my opinion, is a bad implementation. .Net MVC itself is somewhat of an aging dinosaur and forcing you to bury your react code in C# classes is not something I would prefer.